# Plant (weed?) Identification

Tags: identification

This has sprung up in a couple of spots in my garden in Kent, UK. I can't place it, and assume it's a weed of some kind. Can anyone identify it before I pull it all out? (The one with the long, slender leaves).

[image]

Comment: Not sure it is a "weed" (from my list). To me it seem more an escapee plant from an other garden. The leaves on bottom part are very large for normal grass..

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it's not a grass. I thought rose bay willowherb maybe but I've got that elsewhere and the young plants' habit is quite different. I hope it's an escapee or something that I've sown and forgotten about!

Answer (score 1):

So, I can finally identify this as campanula (bellflower). I noticed some in my neighbour's garden and asked her if she'd planted hers. So said she had not, so goodness knows where it's all seeded from.